# How to loop trough a list in python?

Tags: python

I want to loop trough a list, but it can only loop once since I did a `for i in range(1)`.

I would like to loop trough the entire list but I don't know how.

this is my code:

```
  def mark_employee_unavailability(service,employee, reason, event_start, event_end):

    with open('info_inspecteurs.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)


        for i in range(len(data)):
             if data[i]['n_inspecteur'] == employee:
                 event_email = data[i]['email_inspecteur']
                 location = data[i]['ad_inspecteur']

        for i in range(1):

            startStrip = datetime.datetime.strptime(event_start, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            endStrip = datetime.datetime.strptime(event_end, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            dayOfWeek = startStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
            # les bons formats
            currentStart = str(startStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).replace(" ", "T")
            currentEnd = str(endStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).replace(" ", "T")
            calendarEnd = str(endStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 1)).replace(" ", "T")


            events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=currentStart + "-00:00",
                                                  maxResults=30, timeMax=calendarEnd + "-00:00",
                                                  singleEvents=True, orderBy='startTime').execute()
            events = events_result.get('items', [])

            currentEmployees = []
            for event in events:
                currentEmployees.append(event['summary'])

            for i in range(1):
                event_done = False
                if employee not in currentEmployees:
                    event_done = True
                else:
                    for event in events:
                        if employee == event['summary'] and str2datetime(currentStart) <= str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) >= str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):
                            event_done = False
                            print(employee + ' est occupé')
                            break
                        else:
                            event_done = True


            if event_done:
                option = show_message_box(QMessageBox.Critical,
                                      "Confirmation",
                                      "Voulez-vous bloquer cette plage horraire?"\
                                      "L'employé portant le nom \"" + employee + "\" a été marqué comme indisponible en raison de : " + reason, \
                                      "Nom de l'employé: " + employee + "\n" \
                                      "Raison: " + reason + "\n" \
                                      "À partir du : " + currentStart + "\n" \
                                      "À ce jour " + currentEnd + "\n"
                                      )

                if option == QMessageBox.Yes:
                    #register_event(service, event)
                    event_done = True
                else:
                    print("Événement ignoré!")
                    event_done = False
                    break

                if event_done:
                    event = {
                        'summary': employee,
                        'location': location,
                        'description': reason,
                        'start': {
                            'dateTime': currentStart,
                            'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
                        },
                        'end': {
                            'dateTime': currentEnd,
                            'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
                        },
                        'attendees': [
                            {'email': event_email},
                        ],
                        'reminders': {
                            'useDefault': True,
                        },
                    }
                    register_event(service, event)

            else:
                second_message_box(QMessageBox.Critical,
                                      "ATTENTION!",
                                      "L'inspecteur " + employee + " est déjà occupé à ce moment-là.""\n" \
                                      "Veuillez essayer une autre plage horraire.", QMessageBox.Ok)
```

EDIT:

I built a small app. It's purpose is to add employees to a google calendar. Each company has it's own set of assigned employees (3 max).

So if Company ABC wants an appointment, I select said company, and it checks if employee1 is free in the calendar, if he's free, it will book the appointment, else it will check if employee2 is free, then employee3 if necessary.

Then, I also added another tab in the app, it's purpose is to be able to block employees if they have vacations, sick leaves, and other things. The purpose of this second tab is for the program to loop over an employee that has vacations, or other thing blocking him from being selected for an appointment.

The issue that I'm having right now is that I the program permits me to add lets say a vacation for someone that is already booked for an appointment. It should not let me to that.

So I will resume the code above :

- Open JSON file where all the employees are stored
- When I select the employee in the GUI, it matches the employee in the JSON file and grabs his information.
- Then, since I only add one date in the GUI, and this is the only date i want to book an employee for a vacation per example, I did a for i in range(1) and then I formatted the dates so they can fit in the google calendar.
- event represent the events you can find in the google calendar
- then, I appended all the names (SUMMARY) of the employees of selected date in a list (currentEmployees)
- then, i set the event_done to false (event_done is the condition to add an event, you will see later)
- then, i say, if employee is not in the list of all the employees in selected date (currentEmployees), then event_done = true (so the event can be booked, since the name of the employee in question is not even found in the list)
- else, if you find him, check if the date I chose overlaps the date already in calendar.
- if so, then event_done set to false
- if not, then event_done set to true
- if event_done, a msgbox will appear and ask if you really want to add this event to this employee
- if i click yes, event_done will be set to true, if i can click no, event_done will be set to false
- and finally, in the end, if event_done is true, it will create this event in the calendar !

Comment: you are breaking the loop after first iteration.  both if and else break, so it will always break.  when do you want it to stop searching for employees?  you should only have break on one of the conditions

Comment: because I used to only have to check one event in the calendar, but now i see that it may be way more than 1 per day and it got me lost @user120242

Comment: if you have to check all events for validity, you need to remove both `break` statements, and remove one of the `event_done =` statements.  When are you sure that event is done?  Your event_done flag setting probably needs to be adjusted, because it doesn't look right

Comment: oh, you have to check all events for overlap?  how efficient does this need to be?  You'll have to sort them to get any kind of performance out of this

Comment: to make this question answerable, you should provide a data set input, and a desired output, and then a clear statement of your goal along with what you have tried so far(this last part you have already posted, but without the prior this won't really be answerable)

Comment: lets say I chose Mark. If mark not in the list, event_done will be set to true, else, if mark is in the list, it will check if the new event overlap the existing one. If not, event_done will be set to true, else, to false. @user120242

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense as-is -- it looks like you have an `event` and `employee` defined outside the scope of this code, and you're doing a lot of checks based on those singular values where it's not clear if that's what is actually supposed to be happening or if that's the part that needs to be in a loop.

Comment: remove the last `break` statement.  if that doesn't fix the problem, more context is needed.  As @Samwise has said, the code doesn't make a whole lot of sense on its own right now.

Comment: How are you representing an employee? What is the rule that tells you whether or not an employee is occupied? What exactly should the *complete* output be? What is the purpose of setting the value for `event_done`? What is the reason for doing all these comparisons of the `str2datetime` results? What is the *actual problem you are trying to solve*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I updated my post. I hope it clears all your questions.

Comment: FYI range(1) returns [0,1], which just makes that loop twice.  I don't see anything immediately wrong with the code you have.  I would check to make sure strtodatetime is generating the correct datetimes, and that the employee checking code is working as intended.  Note that right now it only appears to be checking one employee against many employees.

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in currentEmployees:
```

This will loop through the entire list vs just looping once

Answer (score -1):

You have already iterated over a list or list-like object before in your code i.e. `events`.

You can do the same for the other list too:

Replace:

```
for i in range(1):
```

to:

```
for i in <list>:
```

or

```
for i in range(len(<list>)):
```